# Select element by using the child

Tags: xpath

I always found my answer before but this time I can't find it. I'm sure you can help me out.

**[Asset]**

[image]

I have to check an asset and I would like to take the one which doesn't contains 'MOVIE' on the subtitle.
So I made those XPATH, both are working but I can't join them.

That one found 2 results, but I would like only the one who doesn't contains Movie.

1

> //a[@class="text-left meta-header-title ellipsis" and text()='Sex and the City']

That's one is working, and selecting only the one which doesn't contain MOVIE, but it's static.

2

> //div[@class="predictive-result-container"]//div[@class="meta-row
>   meta-detail no-gutter"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2byBB.png)[not(contains(.,'MOVIE'))]

And I can't joined 1 + /div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2byBB.png)[not(contains(.,'MOVIE'))]

> //a[@class="text-left meta-header-title ellipsis" and text()='Sex and the  - City']/*//div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2byBB.png)[not(contains(.,'MOVIE'))]

doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share HTML sample for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I can't have the access of the first case for the moment, but I found exactly the same on mobile for another title.

The name is "The A-Team". And I found the solution :)

There is the code :

```
<XCUIElementTypeOther x="0" height="368" width="750" visible="false" y="292" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeOther" />
                              <XCUIElementTypeButton x="690" height="68" width="60" name="headerMoreInfoButton" visible="true" y="288" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeButton" />
                              <XCUIElementTypeCell x="0" height="176" width="750" name="DFWCollectionCell" visible="true" y="468" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeCell">
                                 <XCUIElementTypeOther x="0" height="176" width="750" visible="true" y="468" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeOther">
                                    <XCUIElementTypeImage x="32" height="144" width="256" name="DFWCollectionCell.imageViewMain" visible="false" y="484" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeImage" />
                                    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText x="304" height="42" width="430" name="DFWCollectionCell.labelOverTitle" value="The A-Team" visible="true" y="484" enabled="true" label="The A-Team" type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" />
                                    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText x="304" height="36" width="430" name="DFWCollectionCell.labelSubTitle" value="TV Show  |  Drama, Action" visible="true" y="524" enabled="true" label="TV Show  |  Drama, Action" type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" />
                                 </XCUIElementTypeOther>
                                 <XCUIElementTypeOther x="32" height="2" width="688" visible="true" y="468" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeOther" />
                              </XCUIElementTypeCell>
                              <XCUIElementTypeCell x="0" height="176" width="750" name="DFWCollectionCell" visible="true" y="644" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeCell">
                                 <XCUIElementTypeOther x="0" height="176" width="750" visible="true" y="644" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeOther">
                                    <XCUIElementTypeImage x="32" height="144" width="256" name="DFWCollectionCell.imageViewMain" visible="false" y="660" enabled="true" type="XCUIElementTypeImage" />
                                    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText x="304" height="42" width="430" name="DFWCollectionCell.labelOverTitle" value="The A-Team" visible="true" y="660" enabled="true" label="The A-Team" type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" />
                                    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText x="304" height="36" width="430" name="DFWCollectionCell.labelSubTitle" value="MOVIE  |  2010" visible="true" y="700" enabled="true" label="MOVIE  |  2010" type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" />
                                    <XCUIElementTypeStaticText x="304" height="36" width="430" name="DFWCollectionCell.labelDescription" value="Next Sunday, 9:00a  |  TBSHD" visible="true" y="736" enabled="true" label="Next Sunday, 9:00a  |  TBSHD" type="XCUIElementTypeStaticText" />
                                 </XCUIElementTypeOther>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is :

So, I want the one which as MOVIE as label on the second child of typeOther:

```
//XCUIElementTypeOther[XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value="The A-Team"] and XCUIElementTypeStaticText[contains(@value, "MOVIE")]]
```

And the one which as not MOVIE as label on the second child :

```
//XCUIElementTypeOther[XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value="The A-Team"] and not(*[contains(@label,"MOVIE")])]
```